# Missing CSFR_TOKEN session attribute after login process in Spring Security with Angular JS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-aspects

I have an issue with Spring Security with AngularJS using CSRF.

My implementation is based on this documentation:

http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

My issue is that *login/logout* process are not managed correctly.

The login phase seems to going well: the response is OK, the Java session is created and there is an attribute "**SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT**" with the **Principal** that is logged.
But after the login process, I noticed that in the session object the attribute for **CSFR_TOKEN is missing**.

This cause this effect: when I try the logout, I pass the request with all headers needed by Spring Security.
But the "*doFilterInternal*" method of *org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter* class can't retrieve the attribute:

```
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN
```

This cause a regeneration of the token because *"the token is missing"* (in session object, not in the request headers), so when the "doFilterInternal" makes the matching control 
with the token passed in the request, the match fails and in the Spring log it prints: *"Invalid CSRF token found for ..."*

This problem stops the filter chain: the filter created in the custom "csrfHeaderFilter" is not called because is called after the standard filter, so I have this error page as a return:

**HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?**

**The session is not expired**. In fact, if I make a refresh of the page on the browser, I can see that I am still logged-in.
And in the logs I can see that the username is still present, and in the session is perfectly saved the Principal object.

If I retry the logout **AFTER** the page refresh, the logout doesn't fail anymore, because in the session the attribute **"CSRF_TOKEN"** is now present.
And the logout process is managed perfectly, because after that I have an empty session in the request.

What's wrong on that?

Here is my actual security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityContextConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Resource(name = "myUserDetailService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public static StandardPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() throws Exception {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/main.html","/pages/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/main.html");
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                        .getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null
                            && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
          HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
          repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
          return repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Bean(name="authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setObjectPostProcessor(ObjectPostProcessor<Object> objectPostProcessor) {
        super.setObjectPostProcessor(objectPostProcessor);
    }
}
```

These are the request headers at the **first logout attempt (without refresh)**

```
HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?

Request URL:https://localhost:8080/myApp/logout
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:[::1]:8080

Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=DFE1A9492F421EDBAEC0DAE6726BFDC4; XSRF-TOKEN=70e2a706-db6d-4f53-b39f-01f6f10b6af1
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:https://localhost:8080
Referer:https://localhost:8080/myApp/main.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
X-XSRF-TOKEN:70e2a706-db6d-4f53-b39f-01f6f10b6af1

Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:1116
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 19 Apr 2016 12:51:09 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved by myself.

The problem was on client-side, I had omitted an http get to the url 'user/', after post-login.
Without this call, the CSRF_TOKEN wasn't resaved in the session, causing the problem on server-side in logout process.

After this fix, the behaviour is correct and it works perfectly.

So, following the Spring-AngularJS tutorial, there is a call to the url 'user', if esit OK followed by a call to the url 'user/'.